# Python eval_cli_line()

Tags: python, simics

`eval_cli_line("cache_%s" % cpu.name + ".ptime")` in my python script is constantly giving the following error

*`NameError: global name 'eval_cli_line' is not defined`*

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes. Read the error message. `eval_cli_line()` is not defined. It's like if I told you to "frobnozzle the porcupine." Unless I define what "frobnozzling" is to you, you would be unable to understand the command, and the porcupine would remain unfrobnozzled.

Comment: Are you using `Simics`, by any chance?

Comment: Where is `eval_cli_line` defined?

Comment: Yes I am trying to use it in a python script and running it through simics.

Comment: I thought eval_cli_line is a pre defined function and I am possibly missing an import

Comment: This is probably a good question to begin asking by using your friendly search engine.  I looked at your question and used Google to search for eval_cli_line and figured out right away that it was an import error.  The first commenter in this list is trying to tell you that but I really think it could have been done more politely. This is a great place to find answers but a lot of folks expect you to have done some research first.

Answer (score 1):

In Simics 4.x, eval_cli_line has been replaced with run_command(). Read the migration guide.